# CYGWIN DEBUG DO NOT FIND THE PATH OF THE EXECUTABLE TO LAUNCH

Tags: gdb, cygwin, eclipse-cdt

I am tryng to set up a CYGWIN toolchain in eclipe. My setup is: Windows 10, eclpise for C 2022-12, cycgwin (gcc, gdb, ecc... correct installed)
I can build correct but I have problem with debug. When I run the debug I get the error attached to the end.
It's seems that the debuger can not run the .exe due to incorrect path. I tried to add some Path mapping in debug config like /cygdrive/c - C:\ but without success.

Could you help me?

---

Error in final launch sequence:

Failed to execute MI command:
-exec-run
Error message from debugger back end:
Error creating process /cygdrive/c/Users/aless/eclipse/C:/Users/aless/eclipse-c-workspace/test/C:/Users/aless/eclipse-c-workspace/test/Debug/test.exe, (error 2).
Failed to execute MI command:
-exec-run
Error message from debugger back end:
Error creating process /cygdrive/c/Users/aless/eclipse/C:/Users/aless/eclipse-c-workspace/test/C:/Users/aless/eclipse-c-workspace/test/Debug/test.exe, (error 2).
Error creating process /cygdrive/c/Users/aless/eclipse/C:/Users/aless/eclipse-c-workspace/test/C:/Users/aless/eclipse-c-workspace/test/Debug/test.exe, (error 2).

Comment: can you run GDB outside Eclipse ?

Comment: yes I can. Using MinGW everything is ok.